# TikZ: Move text a little higher

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes

What do I have to change in the following definition, so that the text is a little bit higher?

```
\newcommand{\header}[3]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node [rectangle, fill=fillheader, anchor=north, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=4cm] (box) at (current page.north){};
    \node [anchor=center] (name) at (box) {%
      \fontsize{40pt}{72pt}\color{header}%
      {\thinfont #1}{\bodyfont  #2}
    };
    \node [anchor=north] at (name.south) {%
      \fontsize{14pt}{24pt}\color{header}%
      \thinheader {\Huge \vphantom{A}} #3%
     };
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \vspace{2.5cm}
  \vspace{-2\parskip}
}
```

Sorry about the maybe stupid question, but I really don't see any intuitive structure in TikZ code, and reaaaaaaaally don't feel like spending a week to understand it.

Comment: Could you add a complete but minimal document where you use this header? And by `a little bit higher` what do you mean? Do you want the header moves up on the page or a taller font?

Comment: http://www.latextemplates.com/template/friggeri-resume-cv

I am using this template, does this qualify as an MWE?

And I mean that ideally I would be able to tweak some value and then move everything 2mm up.

Comment: I don't have Helvetica Neue font, so it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Hmm, sorry, I hacked some horrible stuff together to make it work, but if open the .cls file and search for the lines `\newfontfamily\bodyfont[]{HelveticaNeueLTStd-Roman}
\newfontfamily\thinfont[]{HelveticaNeue-UltraLight}
\newfontfamily\headingfont[]{Helvetica Neue-BoldCond}`, maybe you just can set them to something that you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a shorter box, try `minimum height=3cm` or whatever. For text higher within a 4cm box, try `\node [anchor=north] (name) at (box.north)` or `\node [anchor=center] (name) at ([yshift=5mm]box)`, say.